# Negative value for Intercept, in lme() output, when all observations are positive

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am currently using R to analyse some animal science data. Among other things I am trying to compare the level of Somatic Cells in milk between 3 different breeds of dairy cattle, taking the the number of lactations into account. Since I include animals from different farms, I include the variable "Farm" as a random effect.In this model, CCS stands for the variable "Cells" (x1000/ml)

Here´s my input:

```
modeloCCS2<-lme(CCS~Raça*Lactação,random=~1|Exploração,data=dados_ind_i)

summary(modeloCCS2)
```

(please bare in mind that there are in Portuguese (Raça=Race; Lactação=Lactation; Exploração=Farm)

This is the output I get:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: dados_ind_i 
      AIC      BIC   logLik
  13597.3 13635.28 -6790.65

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Exploração
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    33.13131 685.9871

Fixed effects: CCS ~ Raça * Lactação 
                     Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)      -87.88849  60.43166 849 -1.454345  0.1462
RaçaHM           162.06695 133.54107 849  1.213611  0.2252
RaçaHS           122.31696 151.73261 849  0.806135  0.4204
Lactação         175.63920  20.53308 849  8.553965  0.0000
RaçaHM:Lactação -105.84623  45.08666 849 -2.347617  0.0191
RaçaHS:Lactação  -59.41401  55.04796 849 -1.079314  0.2808

Correlation: 
                (Intr) RaçaHM RaçaHS Lactaç RçHM:L
RaçaHM          -0.429                            
RaçaHS          -0.371  0.179                     
Lactação        -0.823  0.383  0.335              
RaçaHM:Lactação  0.369 -0.865 -0.159 -0.462       
RaçaHS:Lactação  0.304 -0.147 -0.865 -0.376  0.181

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.39106435 -0.35941829 -0.14182631  0.02411657 10.19896065 

Number of Observations: 858
Number of Groups: 4
```

As you can see, the estimate for the intercept is negative. But all the observations from CCS are strictly positive! If the intercept is the estimate of the mean value of CCS for that group, how can it be negative?

Can someone shed some light on this matter?

Here´s the out put of `str(dados_ind_i)`:

```
 > str(dados_ind_i)
'data.frame':   858 obs. of  21 variables:
 id                     : Factor w/ 858 levels "1001","1002",..: 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 ...
 Exploração             : Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 Nº.Animal              : int  3963 4099 4124 4168 4176 4189 4208 4222 4239 4241 ...
 Raça                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "H","HM","HS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 Estado                 : Factor w/ 9 levels "Abort","Cedo",..: 4 6 9 9 6 4 5 7 7 4 ...
 Nascimento             : Factor w/ 1021 levels "01/01/2011","01/01/2014",..: 249 957 590 602 605 240 924 588 181 269 ...
 Idade..anos.           : num  10.3 9.1 8.8 8.4 8.3 8.1 8 8 7.8 7.8 ...
 Lactação               : int  7 6 5 6 6 5 5 5 5 6 ...
 Data.última.IA         : Factor w/ 371 levels "","01/01/2017",..: 167 255 153 56 364 167 1 366 290 328 ...
 DIM.à.1ª.IA            : int  55 49 59 54 46 39 NA 64 97 50 ...
 Nº.IA                  : int  3 10 1 6 3 4 NA 5 7 2 ...
 IEP                    : int  460 567 NA NA 367 419 NA 709 530 356 ...
 Dias.abertos           : int  180 287 NA NA 87 139 NA 429 250 76 ...
 DIM                    : int  197 478 105 306 205 156 131 484 316 108 ...
 Produção.média.dia     : num  23.5 26.1 23 54.2 47.8 42.7 46.1 29.8 33.1 59 ...
 Produção.durante.a.vida: int  72111 88022 72511 82376 76533 77694 65443 63018 68724 70842 ...
 Gordura                : num  3.64 4.62 5.81 2.62 3.45 5.79 2.64 4.27 3.56 3.83 ...
 Proteína               : num  3.15 3.47 2.88 3.05 2.86 2.85 3.02 3.67 3.16 2.94 ...
 CCS                    : int  1457 6364 1119 819 274 19 2289 90 378 140 ...
```

Thank you

Comment: This can easily happen with ordinary (simple) regression as well.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: How are the two variables coded? Are they 0-1? Or something else? Or is either one continuous?

Comment: The variable "Raça" (Breed in English) can be H, HM or HS, which are the different breeds. The variable CCS can have values from 0 (0 not included) up and is discrete. I am trying to measure differences in CCS between the different breeds

Comment: If the dependent variable is discrete, you shoujld not be doing linear regression, you should be doing multinomial logistic or ordinal logistic.

Comment: It's worth noting that the negative intercept is not significant.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I made a mistake answering to your comment, Peter Flom. The variable CCS is not discrete! It can have values from 0 up and doesn't have a limit.I am sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: To clarify the type and coding of the data, can you give the output of `str(dados_ind_i)`?

Comment: @BrentKerby, I edited the question with the output you requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in comments this can easily happen even with ordinary simple regression. It doesn't even require anything out of the ordinary, as long as the smallest x-value is somewhat positive it's quite easy to do -- here's a couple of randomly generated examples:

[image]
[image]

(You can actually have it happen even when the smallest x-value is negative but it's less trivial to obtain)

In your case I'd guess the "lactations" variable would be playing a similar role to $x$ here, when looking at at the baseline (H) level of Raça.

Comment: Thank you. So...if I understand correctly: this might happen because, in the group H for "Raça" the mean CCS value for the lowest value of "Lactation" is positive but very low, and much lower compared to the CCS values for other lactations?

Comment: ...and having this value, what is the interpretation I can make of the output? If I can make any...

Comment: The intercept is telling you about the mean in the baseline group when lactations variable is 0 (on the average field). This is probably not interesting unless you have cases where lactations actually is 0 and the model fits well (in particular, that the relationship with lactations is actually linear - which I suspect it may not be). So (i) I wouldn't seek to interpret the intercept at all unless there was some particular reason to think that would make sense  and (ii) I'd be focused on considering if I had a reasonable model.

Comment: It's not simply that the mean of one group is low (it could happen for example. that the intercept for *any* group taken as baseline was negative); it relates to the size and direction of the relationship and how low the mean is at the lowest values of the continuous variable

Comment: Thank you very much @Glen_B. In fact, I do not have cases where lactation is zero.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended to supplement Glen_b's answer and to follow up on your question in the comment about how to interpret the output.

If we take the model output literally, it means that it estimates a mean CCS of -88 for breed H given zero lactations. Clearly this is a nonsensical estimate, but it may or may not indicate a problem with the model, depending on what you are trying to do. The question is whether a case of zero lactations falls within the scope of what you want the model to describe (and whether the concept of a CCS measurement even makes sense in a case of zero lactations). If the answer is no, then the intercept is only telling you what happens when you extrapolate beyond the domain that you are interested in (and possibly beyond the range that is physically meaningful). In that case, the intercept is not relevant in interpreting the model, and it is not a problem that it is estimated as negative. It would only be a problem if the model gives negative estimates of mean CCS for lactation quantities within the range that you intend the model to address. It's worth noting that your model gives positive estimates of mean CCS as long as the number of lactations is at least 2.

Comment: Dear @BrentKerby. Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, the observations do not include one single case of zero lactations (and that would not be very realistic in this analisis in particular) so I believe this intercept value is not relevant at all. Once again, thank you for your help; I am only a Vet student trying to get a grasp of the statistics for the final dissertation. Thank you!